# Use a web api from another tenant - Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I’d like to use scopes in our Azure B2C instance, however all our resources are residing in a different active directory. Can I somehow also select the API instance from another Resource? Or is it possible to upgrade our main AD to an Azure B2C one? Or can we somehow move our subscription and all resources to our Azure B2C AD?

Answer (score 0):

At this point in time, Azure AD B2C does not support multi-tenancy. You can vote and keep track of the feature in the Azure AD B2C UserVoice forum:

- [How to use Multitenant Applications Based on B2C](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/9849063-aadb2c-how-to-on-multi-tenant-applications-based)

Without multitenancy, you will not be able to access resources from other tenants. It is also not possible to upgrade your main AD to an Azure AD B2C tenant, or have subscriptions within your Azure AD B2C Tenant.

Not entirely sure what your scenario is, but the recommended way to do this is by adding Azure AD as an identity provider. This currently can be done [using custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-aad-custom), but I would encourage waiting until the feature is available through built-in policies.